# How to use awk or other command to format user input text string

Tags: string, awk

I have text like followings:
delimited by space

> tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5

or delimited by comma

> tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4,tab5

I want to covert the above text to the following:

> ('tab1','tab2','tab3','tab4','tab5')

or

> 'tab1','tab2','tab3','tab4','tab5'

How to do it? 
Thank you very much for your help!

Amos

Comment: so you don't want to cover the case where your input data might include a space in the value?, ie `tab1 tab 2withspace tab3 tab4` ? It will simplify your life considerably, if you decide on one kind of input format, and use a field separator value that cannot be included by your data source, ie `tab1|tab 2 with space|tab3| ...`. Good luck.

Comment: shellter, thank you very much for your comments. I didn't realize there could be a such problem. It definitely would be nice to have a built-in logic to handle situation like that, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat file
tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5
tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4,tab5

$ awk -v OFS="','" -v start="'" -v end="'"  '{$1=$1; print start $0 end}' file
'tab1','tab2','tab3','tab4','tab5'
'tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4,tab5'

$ awk -v OFS="','" -v start="('" -v end="')"  '{$1=$1; print start $0 end}' file
('tab1','tab2','tab3','tab4','tab5')
('tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4,tab5')

$ awk -F, -v OFS="','" -v start="('" -v end="')"  '{$1=$1; print start $0 end}' file
('tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5')
('tab1','tab2','tab3','tab4','tab5')

$ awk -F, -v OFS="','" -v start="'" -v end="'"  '{$1=$1; print start $0 end}' file
'tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5'
'tab1','tab2','tab3','tab4','tab5'
```